# Intercept Jax-RS method invocation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, resteasy

I'd like to intercept every method call for methods that are annotated with `@HttpMethod` or some sub-annotation of that.

It isn't convenient for me to create an annotation, that I put on every method that can be invoked by Jax-RS, so I turned to `WriterInterceptor` and `ReaderInterceptor`.

However, these aren't what I'm looking for, since I'd like it to intercept the method invocation, instead of the reading/writing process.

Filters are not good enough since I don't get to catch exceptions thrown by the method.

The first solution (plain java-ee interceptor) would be the best option if I didn't have to annotate every method with an arbitrary annotation.

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1):

This may be container specific but on at least Wildfly 18 I think I can do what you want.  I'm using a servlet filter and pure JAX-RS - nothing RestEasy specific (nor Spring).  My `Application` code does:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestApplicationConfig extends Application {
    // intentionally empty
}
```

My Filter is:

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/rest/*")
public class FilterTest implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) {

        try {
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        }
        catch( Throwable t ) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I do a try/catch around the `doFilter` call.  This is where you can catch any exceptions.  An interesting addition is that I have a `ContainerRequestFilter` also:

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
@PreMatching
public class AuthContainerRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException  {
    }
}
```

and the `catch` in the Filter is not called until this code runs in Wildfly.  That makes sense as this is the JAX-RS part.

My "service" is just:

```
@Path("/v1/exception")
public class ExceptionService {
    @Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
    @GET
    public Response getException() {
        throw new InternalError("this is an internal error");
    }
}
```

Comment: servlet filters didn't come to mind, this sounds like a great idea, thank you, I'll definitely try it